# Makefile runs differently than shell command? (when using cat)

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to turn a command a run manually into a Makefile target, but I'm getting an error relating to my use of `cat`. I think I'm trying to open the file "cat" instead of `cat`'ing the actual file...

```
queries.sql : clean
    ls ./sql/**/*.sql | sort -V | while read fn ; do (cat "${fn}"; echo; echo) >> queries.sql; done
clean :
    rm -f queries.sql;
```

Running the `ls` command on its own works great, but with the Makefile I just get

```
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
cat: : No such file or directory
...
```

I'm a rookie when it comes to this, so it's probably something simple. Also, I believe there is a way to do this without `cat`?

Edit:

Oh and the sql scripts are prefixed by dates i.e. 2020-01-02 so I'd like to keep the filenames sorted as seen by the `ls -V`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the most often asked question about make these days.

The `$` character is special to make, so if you want to pass along a `$` to the shell you have to escape it, by using `$$`.

So `cat "${fn}"` must be written `cat "$${fn}"` in your recipe.

Comment: Awesome! Where would be a helpful place to read about this behavior? I picked up the GNU Make ref manual but I'm not very far; would this potentially be covered in it?

Comment: Certainly.  Try "Basics of Variable References": https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html